# In adding CMS functionality to static website, is complete conversion the only way?

Tags: php, cms

I have a static website that is built in ASP.NET and PHP, and I want to add the functionality of a CMS to it.

I know the most complete way would be to convert the whole site over to WP - mimic the design, theme and navigation of the existing site in WP and go from there.

I wanted to know if it is possible to add bits of WP functionality to existing pages. Or is the only way to add WP functionality to an existing site to add whole new WP pages.

I think this is an odd question but I would appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to add parts, but I would recommend a complete switch as it would save you a lot of maintenance hassle and speed things up in the longrun